# PHP отправка массива

Tags: php, html

```
foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
    if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
        $message .= "
        " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr>' ) . "
          <td><b>$key</b></td>
          <td>$value</td>
        </tr>";
    }
}
```

Без name="" в html не хочет отправлять $value, задача в том что нужно скрыть некоторые $key в письме, т.е чтобы приходили только $value

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос устарел

Comment: если ответ Вас устраивает, отметьте его как решение(серая галка слева от вопроса).

Comment: `$c = !$c` - видимо для зёбры?

Answer (score 0):

Ну так скройте эти key на сервере, в чем проблема-то?

```
foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
    if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
        $message .= "
        " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr>' ) . "
        <td><b>" . (in_array($key, array('key1'. 'key2', 'key100500')) ? '' : $key) . "</b></td>
        <td>$value</td>
    </tr>
    ";
}
```

для записей с именами 'key1'. 'key2', 'key100500' колонка с ключом будет пустой.

PS кстати, а что вот это за магия?

```
( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr>' )
```

Comment: Сам ещё достаточно далекий от PHP, опробовал предложений вами вариант - не пошло, все равно на почту приходят сообщение c $key.
Может плохо объяснил, там 10 инпутов и value с них отправляется если есть name(key) и нужно этот кей скрыть в некоторых полях

Comment: покажите код (html, и как вы в php вставили предложенный вариант). лечить на расстоянии по фотографии иногда выгодно для лекаря, но редко эффективно для пациента :)

Comment: https://github.com/agragregra/uniMail, пользовался этим

Comment: а показать именно ваш код (в т.ч. то, как вы "вставили в php") - вы стесняетесь? ;))

Comment: заодно - показали бы еще текст письма, как он приходит (и что именно удалить надо)

Comment: ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr>' )  - это тернарный оператор. Можно заменить if - else.

Comment: Может вы хотите сделать поля не обязательными для заполнения? Тогда в html в теге <input> уберите слово required